# Pop Up Comment Box In wordpress

Tags: wordpress, popup, comments, box

I Want to show pop up box on my Wordpress blog when someone want to make a comment in archive file , like i have "Leave a Comment" link in my index file and when user click on that it should be pop up with comment box rather than redirect to single post page

i have tried many Plugins but nothing works

this is my code in Wordpress

```
<?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'beautytemple' ), __( '1 Comment', 'beautytemple' ), __( '% Comments', 'beautytemple' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If we are using `comments_popup_link()` function. We have to use `the_loop, have_posts() ,the_post()`. The  `comments_popup_link()` will only work when we are using this function within the loop.